# Trying to find "pure" implementations of LZ77 and LZ78

Tags: algorithm, compression, zlib

I'm trying to find a few "real-world", usable `LZ77` and `LZ78` implementations (be it tools, libraries...) in order to establish a comparison between both of those algorithms.

I know that there exist multiple improvements and combinations of such algorithms, and programs like `compress` implement the `LZW` algorithm, whereas, as far as I know, `zlib` combines `LZ77` with Huffman encoding, which somewhat invalidates it unless I find a better alternative.

Are there no (somewhat) known tools which exclusively use them, be it in its default behavior or by allowing to choose to use them? All I can find is tiny projects in Github.

Comment: BTW, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic". | That said, for LZ77, two real-world tools that come to mind might be LZ4 and Snappy. Basically things where speed (and likely low memory usage) is the primary goal, as opposed to compression ratio.

Comment: (I think LZW/LZC to be pretty straightforward LZ78 implementations.)

Comment: I didn't think that it could be off-topic since I saw this kind of questions in the past, but thank you both! This gives me some stuff to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[lz4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/doc/lz4_Block_format.md) is pretty much just LZ77, without Huffman or other coding, but effciently packing the matches and literals in bits.